# PyGTK How to bind different callback to per clickable text on label?

Tags: python, pygtk

I want to connect the callback to text of label

for example at following code

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk

def hello(*args):
    print "hello, this is most used text editor for pyton"

def wellcome(*args):
    print "wellcome to the our program please update to premium version"


w = gtk.Window(title = "example", type = gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
w.resize(300, 200)

mylabel = gtk.Label()
mylabel.set_markup("""please read """
                   """<span underline = "single" command = "hello">hello</span> or """
                   """<span underline = "single" command = "wellcome">wellcome</span>""")


w.add(mylabel)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

I know, pango span attribute does not contain the command option, okay. Is there a another way to do it?

Comment: You need to use two `Gtk.Button`s and connect to the `clicked` signal of them.

Comment: @elya5, can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by connecting your handler to the `activate-link` signal. Note that the signature of the callback is different from a button click, and that you should return True to stop further processing.

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup('<a href="mylink">Click Here</a> but not here.')
        label.connect("activate-link", self.on_link_clicked)
        self.add(label)

    def on_link_clicked(self, label, uri):
        print("%s clicked" % uri)
        return True

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this answer do not solve my problem,  that underlined (clickable) label opens the link on browser. I do not want it to open in the browser

Comment: Did you return True in the callback? Please run my code exactly as it is written, or post your code.

Comment: yes it works well. but there is a small problem. how can i bind different callback per clickable text ?

Comment: does anybody know ?

Comment: You don't need different handlers. Add a different uri for the other link, and check the uri value in the same handler. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: okey, i accepted but please  give a better example for other persons. please change the code of your answer and add the if block. for example: if uri == "mylink"

Answer (score 0):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup('please read <a href="hello">Hello</a> or <a href="wellcome">wellcome</a>')
        label.connect("activate-link", self.on_link_clicked)
        self.add(label)

    def hello(self):
        print "hello, this is most used text editor for pyton"

    def wellcome(self):
        print "wellcome to the our program please update to premium version"

    def on_link_clicked(self, label, uri):
        print("%s clicked" % uri)

        if uri == "hello":
            self.hello()
        elif uri == "wellcome":
            self.wellcome()

        return True

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```